# How to keep radio button selected when the corresponding Activity is minimized?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have an `Activity`. There are two radio button in this activity. I want to keep radio button selected (Which one selected) if I go to another activity or minimized the apps. 
Now What can I do?
If anyone can do this please help me.

Comment: try to save the radiobutton state in Bundle and reload the state of the button within the onResume()

Answer (score 0):

Any Activity restart its `onResume()` method executed first.

if you use this method following way.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // put your code here...

      if (your condition){
            radioButton.setChecked(true); //check accrodingly which button you want to set checked
      }else{
            radioButton.setChecked(false);
     }
    }
```